# How do i split a value in model class

Tags: c#

How do i split a value in model class.

in `list[0].key = 1` and `list[0].value = 1_5`

here is the code:

```
   if (data.Things.Count != 0)
            {
                var ans = new List<QuestionModel>();
                ans = data.Things.Select(item =>
                {
                    return new QuestionModel()
                    {
                        QuestionId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Key),
                        AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value),

                    };
                }).ToList();

            }
```

here i want to split the value.i.e. in AnswerId  want only 5.

Comment: What are the possible Values for "AnswerId"?

Comment: So you want to split `1_5` into `1` and `5`? And what is the problem? Have you even had a look at `String.Split`?

Comment: AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value),  what should i write??AnswerId  is the int value

Comment: in data.Things of columns there is two values one is key and value i want to spilit and assign in model

Comment: If this answers helped you, it is polite to accept the one you think best answers your question. It also helps people searching for help on an issue similar to yours to see that there is an accepted answer. It's what makes SO so useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want the part after the underscore, and it's *always* an underscore in the format of `item.Value`, you can do this:

```
item.Value.Split('_')[1];
```

This splits the string on the `_` and then takes the second part (e.g. what is after the `_`).

So the complete line of code would be:

```
AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value.Split('_')[1]),
```

I would add that the fact you are having to do something this clunky is perhaps a symptom of your model not being a good fit to your domain - if you are able to refactor your model such that you don't have to do this and the field in question contains *only* the data you are interested in then your solution would be cleaner and more easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Come on. Value is a string value right? Did you look at string class what methods does it have? There is a method called split. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

In short:

```
string value = "1_5";
string[] arr = value.Split('_');
//now arr[0] is "1" and arr[1] is "5"

int i = Convert.ToInt(arr[1]);
```

Comment: without taking the array how do i direct split??

Comment: int i = Convert.ToInt(value.Split('_')[1]);

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, what you're trying to achieve, but I think you want to split the string "1_5" and retrieve just the "5". This can be achieved using `string.Split()`:

```
(item.Value.Split('_'))[1]
```

Comment: AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value), how do i split so that answerid is int value

Comment: The entire line would be: `AnswerId = Convert.ToInt32((item.Value.Split('_'))[1])`